# AWS CloudWatch Billing metrics Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I am attempting to use CloudWatch AWS/Billing metrics to consolidate cost information in a central aggregator.

All the guides I can find seem to just point to setting "Receive Billing Alerts" on the master payer account.  After doing that the metrics appear on that 'root' account.  But none of the other accounts or users can see them.

UPDATE: I can get the data if I make a new IAM user in the Root Account, but i felt that since my user could see the Billing dashboard, it should also be able to see the CloudWatch metrics

Comment: Hi, can you confirm that this question is you're trying to setup centralised billing to a single account? :)

Comment: No, I want to create a dashboard in a third party app.  It will consolidate AWS, Azure, Google, and some custom data.

I can get the data if I make the account in the Root Account, but i felt that since my user could see the Billing dashboard, it should also be able to see the CloudWatch metrics